# Bluestacks installer not working

Tags: desktop-application, bluestacks

The Bluestacks installer extracts and then after allowing the installer it shows Bluestacks installer in the taskbar and it dissappears. I have got all the system requirements right. Windows Vista sp2, 2gb RAM, dotNet 4.5

Answer (score 0):

It takes a lot of time. Like hours. Just wait. It will get installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the article, the content is below. You can read if there is a solution.

1- Turn off all other apps
It is possible that your computer is running too many applications, leading to BlueStacks not working. Maybe due to lack of RAM, due to CPU overload. Turning off other applications will help free up RAM and CPU, thereby helping BlueStacks work.

Doing:

Open Task Manager and select each running application. Click on them and select End Task. Remember to charge the laptop battery before starting Bluestack.

2- Restart BlueStacks with Admin rights
Sometimes the cause of Bluestacks Initializing error can be due to lack of Admin rights. Please use Admin rights to open BlueStacks on your computer.

Doing:

Right-click on Bluestacks and select Run as administrator and check if the error is still there.

3- Update to the latest BlueStacks version
After doing the above two ways, it still does not fix the error BlueStacks cannot run, please install the latest version of BlueStacks.

Doing:

Step 1: Uninstall BlueStacks on your computer using Control Panel. Go to Control Panel > Uninstall a Program > Right click on BlueStack and select Uninstall.
Step 2: Visit the BlueStacks website to download the latest version to your computer.

4- Check the required configuration
After reinstalling the latest version, you still can't get into BlueStacks, please check your computer's configuration meets the minimum configuration required by the BlueStacks application:

Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 or later.
CPU: Intel or AMD.
RAM: Your PC must have at least 2GB of RAM. (Disk space 2GB or more is not a substitute for RAM)
HDD: At least 5GB free space
You must be an Administrator on your PC
Updated graphics driver from Microsoft or chipset vendor

Doing:

Right-click This PC > Select Properties.
Check computer configuration
If your computer configuration is lower than the minimum requirements, you should not install BlueStack.
Source: https://thewindowswork.com/guide/4-ways-to-fix-error-bluestacks-not-working-on-windows-10-11